# XPath query for match catch

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

Is there any way to search in XML doc with match case? In this post I see searching with exact match:  [XPath query for exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757987/xpath-query-for-exact-match)

What I want to achieve is to get all matching elements according to  my criteria.

Like if I have the following XML:

```
<Videos>
<Misc  URL="http://ccc/.webm1.webm"  />
<Misc  URL="http://bbb/OGG_2.ogv"  />
<Misc  URL="http://aaa/OGG_3.ogv"  />
<Misc  URL="http://ccc/.webm4.webm"  />
<Misc  URL="http://bbb/OGG_5.ogv"  />
<Misc  URL="http://aaa/OGG_6.ogv"  />
</Videos>
```

I want to get all nodes that contain or having `.ogv`, similarly all that contains `.webm` extensions.

Any idea how to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//Misc[substring(@URL, string-length(@URL)-3)='.ogv']`

The above uses XPath 1.0 and simply performs a substring and returns the last 3 characters to match against `.ogv`.

Also, to simplify the above, using XPath 2.0 `//Videos/Misc[ends-with(@URL, '.ogv')]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Linq-XML.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
var result = doc.Descendants("Misc").Select(p => p.Attribute("URL"))
                     .Where(p => p.Value.EndsWith(".ogv"));
foreach (var t in result)
  Console.WriteLine(t.Value);
```